# Continuing with a postdoc with my PhD advisor, but have not got any official offer letter. Should I be worried?

Tags: postdocs, canada

I am an international student who's currently in a bureaucratic mess regarding my work permit application. I will get my permit possibly in February end. I completed my PhD thesis submission in December. Now, my PhD supervisor offered me a postdoc position soon after my defense, but I cannot officially sign a contract till I get my work permit. So, I don't have any official offer letter with me at the moment.

Should I be worried that I currently have no letter indicating the appointment and how can I handle the situation better?

Comment: Please specify the country.

Comment: @scaaahu Canada

Answer (score 8):

No, you should not be worried. It is perfectly normal for official offer letters to be delayed.  Ask your supervisor if they submitted the necessary paperwork.  Ask HR what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this will be a 3-step process:

1. you get an offer letter that is conditional on you having a work permit
2. you use this offer letter to get the work permit
3. once you have the work permit you sign the offer letter

As you would be without any permit (maybe even without visa?) it is perfectly reasonable if you check the status of the various steps and ask people nicely to speed it along.